# Play Framework: Bad type on operand stack

Tags: java, scala, playframework, jvm, ebean

Code's written in scala but Exception is from java.lang. I am trying to connect my basic scala + play app to database. I am using a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zdt_utUOd5s&list=PLYPFxrXyK0Bx9SBkNhJr1e2-NlIq4E7ED&index=21

Everything worked just like in the video until 7:40 rolled around. Instead of getting the option to run an sql script i get this bizarre error:

> VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
>
> Exception Details:
>
> Location:
>       models/Book.(ILjava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;)V @2: invokevirtual
>
> Reason:
>       Type uninitializedThis (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'models/Book'
>
> Current Frame:
>       bci: @2
>       flags: { flagThisUninit }
>       locals: { uninitializedThis, integer, 'java/lang/String', integer, 'java/lang/String' }
>
> ```
> stack: { uninitializedThis, integer }
> ```
>
> Bytecode:
>       0000000: 2a1b b600 d52a 2cb6 00d8 2a1d b600 db2a
>       0000010: 1904 b600 de2a b700 e12a bb00 e359 2ab7
>       0000020: 00e6 b500 e82a b800 ec2a 1bb6 005a 2a2c
>       0000030: b600 622a 1db6 0069 2a19 04b6 0070 b1

And a bit of Stack Trace:

Here is my models.Book class:

```
package models

import io.ebean.Model
import javax.persistence.{Entity, Id}

@Entity
case class Book(identifier: Int, title1: String, price1: Int, author1: String)  extends Model {
  @Id
  var id: Int = identifier
  var title: String = title1
  var price: Int = price1
  var author: String = author1

  override def toString: String = s"id = $id $title written by $author"
```

And Bookset object

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashSet

object BookSet {


  val set: HashSet[Book] = HashSet[Book]()




  add(Book(1,"C++",20,"This one Danish Guy"))
  add(Book(2,"Java",30,"Sun Mirco"))
  add(Book(3,"Gone with the wind",60,"Some dude"))
  add(Book(4,"Catcher in the Rye",20,"Some other dude"))


  def findById(id: Int): Book = {
    var mybook: Book = null
    set foreach { book =>
      if(book.id == id) mybook = book
    }
    mybook
  }


  def add(book: Book) = {
    set.add(book)
    //bookIndex+=1

  }

  def remove(book: Book) = {
    set.remove(book)
  }
```

I've done all the required prep work (build.sbt, plugins.sbt, app.conf) the guy in the video did. I have the line : `db.default.enabled = true` in my app.conf file and I've added

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(evolutions, jdbc)
```

to build.sbt

I've noticed that after I remove the @Entity annotation i don't get the exception nor the option to run sql script =. What is causing the problem and how do fix it? Is is because I am using Scala classes instead of plain POJO's ?

Comment: Perhaps, it has to do with the fact that you are using a **`case class`** as `@Entity`. The way you’re adding a body to it, duplicating all fields, looks odd. But I’m not a Scala programmer. As a Java programmer, I can tell you that the `VerifyError` says that the generated (or instrumented) byte code tries to invoke instance methods on `this` in the constructor, before the super constructor has been called.

Comment: I agree with @Holger. I will add that this might also be another case of using the Java technology with Scala when it comes to PlayFramework.  EBean is only meant for Java: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaEbean#Configuring-Ebean. For Scala, you will need to go to Anorm, Slick, or Raw JDBC calls.

Comment: Thanks for help guys :) I guess ORM was never meant for me